# How is learning rate decay implemented by Adam in keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I set learning rate decay in my optimizer Adam, such as

```py
LR = 1e-3
LR_DECAY = 1e-2
OPTIMIZER = Adam(lr=LR, decay=LR_DECAY)
```

As the keras document [Adam](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/c10d24959b0ad615a21e671b180a1b2466d77a2b/keras/optimizers.py#L433) states, after each epoch learning rate would be

```
lr = lr * (1. / (1. + self.decay * K.cast(self.iterations, K.dtype(self.decay))))
```

If I understand correctly, learning rate be like this,

```
lr = lr * 1 / ( 1 + num_epoch * decay)
```

But I don't see the learning rate decay come into effect, after seeing that printed out.
Is there any problem when I use this ?

**Edit**
I print out the learning by setting the verbose of the `ReduceLROnPlateau`, such as,

```
ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_loss', factor=0.75, patience=Config.REDUCE_LR_PATIENCE, verbose=1, mode='auto', epsilon=0.01, cooldown=0, min_lr=1e-6
```

And that would monitor the val-loss and reduce the learning rate by multiplying the `factor`.
The printed learning rate is like this,

```
Epoch 00003: ReduceLROnPlateau reducing learning rate to 0.0007500000356230885.
```

And I set the initial learning rate to be 1e-3. Therefore, it appears that the learning rate change from 1e-3 to 1e-3 * 0.75, so I doubt that the `decay` I set in Adam isn't working.

Comment: What do you mean by "I don't see the learning rate decay come into effect"?

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro I also have `ReduceLROnPlateau` to print out the learning rate once the val-loss doesn't reduce. I compared the printed learning rate with the initial learning rate I set, and found out the `decay` I set in Adam didn't seem to reduce the LR in each epoch.

Comment: How exactly are you printing the learning rate?

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro hi, I re-edited my post. Looking forward to your feed back thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The learning rate changes with every iteration, i.e., with every batch and not epoch. So, if you set the decay = 1e-2 and each epoch has 100 batches/iterations, then after 1 epoch your learning rate will be

```
lr = init_lr * 1/(1 + 1e-2 * 100)
```

So, if I want my learning rate to be 0.75 of the original learning rate at the end of each epoch, I would set the lr_decay to

```
batches_per_epoch = dataset_size/batch_size
lr_decay = (1./0.75 -1)/batches_per_epoch
```

It seems to work for me. Also, since the new learning rate is calculated at every iteration, the optimizer doesn't change the value of the learning rate variable and always uses the initial learning rate to calculate the effective learning rate.